# How to handle effect way of JSON parsing from Firebase Remote Config in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

I have various set of configuration in firebase with JSON format.
From App side, i am using data class to parse the firebase remote config.

Data classes:

```
val object1: SampleData1
val object2: SampleData2
```

I am reading the response with below code. Here if any issue with parsing JSON for **object1** it will throw exception so **object2** parsing will not happen in this situation.

What is the best way to handle these scenarios?

```
try {
    object1 = ......
    object2 = .....

} catch(e: Exception) {

}
```

Comment: Hi, did you try parsing `object2` in a separate try-catch?

Comment: Is that good way? because if i have 10 object classes, then i need to add try and catch for each and every class?

Comment: If we have 10 different classes it will be very less efficient even while fetching data, so in those cases either we should do try-catch in the loop on the array or try storing data in fewer classes.

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with firebase remote config and is more generally a programming question.